# Tailwind CSS: 'overflow-y' Property Not Scrolling Entirely to Bottom with 'top-[63px]

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm encountering an issue with my Tailwind CSS code that seems to prevent me from scrolling to the bottom of an aside element.

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <nav class=" bg-white px-2 py-2.5 dark:bg-gray-800 sm:px-4 fixed w-full z-20 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 h-[63px]">

      </nav>
      <aside class="hidden sm:flex h-full " aria-label="Sidebar">
        <div class="">
          <div class="fixed top-[63px] overflow-y-auto z-20 py-5 px-3 w-16 h-full bg-white border-r border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overflow-y-auto fixed top-[63px] left-16 z-20 py-5 px-3 w-64 h-full bg-white border-r border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
          <ul class="overflow-y-auto w-full">
            <li>
              <div class=" pl-2 mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase">Lorem ipsum</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Lorem ipsum</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Lorem ipsum</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- More items -->
            <li>
              <div class=" pl-2 mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase">Lorem ipsum</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Lorem ipsum</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Lorem ipsum</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li> 
            <li>
              <div class="pt-4 pl-2 mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase">Lorem ipsum</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Lorem ipsum</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Last Item</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <div class="sm:pl-16 pt-[63px]">
        here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Issue Explanation:**

I'm using Tailwind CSS classes (top-[63px], overflow-y-auto, etc.) to style the aside element, intending it to be a scrollable sidebar. However, it seems that the top-[63px] style is causing the scrolling to stop before reaching the bottom of the aside, leaving some content inaccessible. In this case `<div class="pl-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-white">Last Item</div>` When there's too many `<li>`

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/vYPEeVB

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to achieving a scrollable aside while maintaining the desired layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom css to 2nd child of aside

```
aside div:nth-child(2) {
  height: calc(100vh - 63px)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do to keep the whole area in view is subtract `63px` from the element height since you are offsetting it from the top. You can use a tailwind class `h-[calc(100vh-63px)]` instead of `h-full` wherever the `top-[63px]` is used. Also note codepen may not reflect the fix so test in your environment.